# Pre-signed URL with SSE

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I try to create a pre-signed url to my bucket which using SSE with the algorithm AES256.

Whenever I'm sending the request (from postman) to my bucket I'm getting back 
    `<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
    <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>
    <AWSAccessKeyId>...</AWSAccessKeyId>
    <StringToSign>AWS4-HMAC-SHA256`

I removed the encryption from my bucket and then everything worked as expected - and therefore I believe that my problem is with the implementation of it...

In order to connect to S3 I created a new bean of AmazonS3EncryptionClientBuilder` by the following code:

```java
var credentials = new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey));
var encryptionMaterials = new StaticEncryptionMaterialsProvider(new EncryptionMaterials(generateSecretKey()));

return AmazonS3EncryptionClientBuilder
                .standard()
                .withCredentials(credentials)
                .withRegion(getClientRegion())
                .withEncryptionMaterials(encryptionMaterials)
                .build();
```

then, in my AmazonSerivce I created the presigned URL be the following code:

```java
final GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest =
                new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(amazonConfiguration.getBucketName(), fileName)
                        .withMethod(HttpMethod.PUT)
                        .withSSEAlgorithm(SSEAlgorithm.AES256);

return s3Client.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest);
```

**EDIT:**

In addition - here are the headers that I'm getting from the url itself:
`response-content-disposition:inline%3B%20filename%3D%2283a9b66c-3ee2-4cc0-851a-266f3d6a81dc%22
X-Amz-Algorithm:AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
X-Amz-Date:20190828T075015Z
X-Amz-SignedHeaders:host%3Bx-amz-server-side-encryption
X-Amz-Expires:1799
X-Amz-Credential:AKIARTL3KQPR6IRHJIKL%2F20190828%2Feu-central-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request
X-Amz-Signature:75854367e3b4eea8ff3a05b7256e47ab1d16f1bf6957c6cd17970b3da217783`

I've added the header `X-Amz-Server-Side-Encryption: AES256` manually while sending the request and got the same error...

Comment: There are 3 variants of SSE: SSE-S3, SSE-KMS, and SSE-C. Which are you trying to use?

Comment: If it's SSE-C, then you'll need to send additional HTTP headers when you use the pre-signed URL. See https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/generating-amazon-s3-pre-signed-urls-with-sse-c-part-4/

Comment: I believe `.withSSEAlgorithm(SSEAlgorithm.AES256)` is SSE-S3, so the request header @jarmod speaks of is `X-Amz-Server-Side-Encryption: AES256`.  Are you adding that header to your request when using the signed URL?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - please look at my edit part - which includes all the headers that I'm having... I added the header manually and the error still exists...

Answer (score 1):

After long investigation it seems that I set the `X-Amz-Server-Side-Encryption` as query parameter and not as a header - and therefore the upload was denied...